# Isometries of a compact semi-simple lie group other than left translations

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, isometry

My understanding is that a left-invariant metric on a compact semi-simple lie group is defined in such a way that left translations are isometries. Bi-invariant metrics do not concern me for the moment. Are there isometries that are not left translations? Infinitesimally, are there killing vector fields that are not left-invariant?

In particular, how to find all isometries on the 3-sphere (i.e. SU(2)), for example? I can write three killing vector fields in terms of coordinate frame field of the ambient 4-dimensional euclidean space; but how to write them intrinsically on the sphere?

Comment: You may find this article to be helpful: https://eudml.org/doc/162876